# Spring Java jumping anchor via fragment-identifier redirects to homepage

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, anchor, fragment-identifier

I've come across a strange problem in a Spring site where if you use jumping anchors, it redirects me to the homepage.

For example, I have code like this (simplified);

```
 <a href="#configuration"><spring:message code='configuration.tab' /></a>
 <a id="configuration" class="noHover"><spring:message code='configuration.tab' /></a>
```

However, when I click the link, my website redirects to my homepage with the jumping anchor suffixed;

http://localhost:8080/web/#configuration

I am thinking this is something to do with the Spring security, but I am not positive.

Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Why do you have to <a> tags - and which one is the one you are talking about (a simple anchor #xxx sould not trigger the browser to send a request, so it is not likely that this is a serverside (springsecurity) related problem)

Comment: I simplified the code base, there is a large amount of text between those two anchors. The first one is part of a table of contents and should jump to the configuration section within the page. This works great in plain html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the cause, I had set the following in my header;

```
<base href="${ctx}/" >
```

Once I removed this code, my jumping anchors started to work properly again via the fragment-identifier. I had done this earlier in the project for convenience.